# How to construct a Custom Comparator function globally?

Tags: c++, comparator

I am new to this concept of constructing custom comparator function.
What I want to know is that can we construct an comparator function which can be used for sorting every type of vector i.e  vector of list  based on second value,sorting map,sorting  descending.

Pls help me with it

Comment: No, each of these situations require a separate comparator function.

Comment: What would you do about types that were never meant to be compared? You'd be much better off relying on the usual `operator<` and friends, which types will provide overloads for if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let, you declared a vector of pairs [a vector containing multiple number of such pairs is called a **vector of pairs**]. And below example is sorting the vector based on second value of pair.

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int>p1, pair<int,int>p2)
{
    // if second value is equal then sorted based on first value
    if(p1.second==p2.second){
        return p1.first<p2.first;
    }
    // otherwise based on second value
    return p1.second<p2.second;
}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int> >vec;
    vec.push_back(make_pair(3,4));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(5,2));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(10,6));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(8,6));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(7,3));
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
    for(auto x:vec){
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<"\n";
    }
    /*
      5 2 
      7 3 
      3 4
      8 6
      10 6
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Try to understand, explore more and implement in code